# Crop dusting regulations in the US

Tags: faa-regulations

What are the regulations regarding crop dusting and flying low over private property. Do they have to file a flight plan and is there a way to make your private property a no fly zone?

Comment: The first part of your question is probably answered in the dupe that @ratchetfreak linked to, but the second one about a private no-fly zone isn't. You might consider making that the main question here.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. You generally can NOT make your property a no-fly zone, as all airspace is part of the US Airspace System (imagine every land owner declared no-fly zones!). That is, of course, if we're talking about the US here, which I assume. If your quest is to prevent a crop duster overflying your property, you'll probably be more successful with other approaches (i. e. not trying to make it a no-fly zone). Perhaps talk with your zoning board, the state, etc., but here as well: crop dusting is usually done in agricultural areas, where crop dusting is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

A crop duster does not have to file a (normal) flight plan. They do have to file a special "operations" plan if they are going to be spraying chemicals. Notice of the intended operation must be given to the public by some effective means, such as daily newspapers, radio, television, or door-to-door notice. A plan for [the spraying] operation must be submitted to, and approved by appropriate personnel of the FAA Flight Standards District Office having jurisdiction over the area where the operation is to be conducted. The plan must include consideration of obstructions to flight; the emergency landing capabilities of the aircraft to be used; and any necessary coordination with air traffic control.

All aircraft must maintain a height of at least 500 feet above ground or objects on the ground, like a house. (Minimum Safe Altitude) A crop duster can go below this height only to operate to apply chemicals and for no other reason. The exact text of the exception reads as follows: "No person may operate an aircraft over a congested area below the altitudes prescribed in part 91 of this chapter except during the actual dispensing operation, including the approaches and departures necessary for that operation."

You cannot prevent someone from flying over your house.

If someone is flying over your house at less than 500 feet, you can file a complaint with the FAA by calling (703) 230-7664. Please observe the following:

• Identification - Can you identify the aircraft? Did you record the registration number which appears on the fuselage or tail? (On U.S. registered aircraft, that number will be preceded with a capital "N".)

• Time and Place - Exactly when did the incident(s) occur? Where did this happen? What direction was the aircraft flying?

• Altitude - How high (low) was the aircraft flying? On what do you base your estimate? Was the aircraft level with or below the elevation of a prominent object such as a tower or building? Did you obtain photographs? Are there any witnesses who could confirm your estimate - do you have their names, addresses, telephone numbers?

• Supporting Evidence

• Witnesses, Police

• Photographs

Comment: The FAA allows lower flight for crop dusters when needed and safe, though.

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote. "All aircraft must maintain a height of at least 500 feet above ground" is positively wrong. (and, I mean, think about it *logically*, have you ever seen a crop duster flying at 500 AGL? They fly low, pretty low, which is actually a danger factor for the pilots, and if they were really flying at 500 AGL or above, it would be a danger for the neighborhood, as the pesticide would reach unintended properties. I also believe that a VFR flight plan is needed, but would have to look into that again. So, given that I have explained myself, I think I'm allowed to downvote.